# How to show value of a classification model even though it doesn't get the desired performance?

Tags: classification, supervised-learning, machine-learning-model

I developed a classification model for a telecom client. Where we classify between Dual-sim and non-Dual-Sim clients. After many iteration the best precision we can get is 60%. The contract says that the acceptance criteria is 75% precision. The client measures precision based on campaign results. In other words, they call sample data and ask them explicitly are a dual sim or not.

Facts we know:

- Learning curve shows that more training data won't do the trick.
- We have got all variables that were used in the market before(and everything we could think of, but nothing improved the model).
- Training data don't even get 1% of the whole population I am generalizing on(and we can't get more than that).
- The random baseline is 35%, so we got a lift of around 1.9 (but they won't approve of it).
- We have tried many iterations from the most simple models to the most complex, and this is the best we can get.
- The dual sim and non-dual sim distribution across the variables, isn't that different.
- The language used were SQL, R.

So the question is, what else can I do to prove that the model has a value but without getting the 75% precision?

Comment: Why do you think the model has value at < 75%

Comment: The model is not able to generalize on the whole base, cause the training data doesn't represent the whole base.

Comment: Which can explain why the model is problematic, but does not necessarily explain why the model has value?

Comment: I understand that the model in not the perfect one. And I have some limitations which won't allow me to improve it. However, if the model is able to perform better than the random by 2 times, then it sure has a value. Which is what I am trying to show to convince them.

Comment: The problem is very abstract...you need to provide more details as the solution might be tailor made

Comment: you mention precision, but how is your recall/f1 score doing?

Comment: @BrunoGL the client is interested in precision cause he will be targeting those people with aggressive offers. So he prefers to target a small number of people who are dual sim rather than targeting a lot of people whom may contain a lot of non-dual people.

Comment: @DuttaA what kind of details could be helpful in this case?

Comment: @hadeer how easy is to manually identify these dual-sim user given your known features?

Comment: @BrunoGL it isn't easy they look a lot similar, and when I try putting strict rules I end up with only a couple of dials.

Comment: @hadeer then maybe that is a way to show value. See how much better humans perform than random and how much your model performs better than humans.

Comment: @hadeer Bonus tip: don't but minimum accuracy acceptance criteria on contracts anymore :P

Comment: @BrunoGL it actually be a good way of showing the value, thanks anyway. And yes we have learnt it the hard way not to put minimum acceptance criteria. 

Comment: @hadeer That is good to hear. Maybe it isn't the best way, but is a good start to slowly teach your customer the truth behind the numbers. Anyways, I will write this then as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often customers don't understand the value behind the performance of machine learning models. 60% precision might sound not so good, since 50% is often related to nearly random for binary problems. However, it might well be a very difficult problem, and 60% might well be very good performance.

One way you can show your customer that your model is indeed performing well, is to compare its precision **against a human classification**.

You can:

1. Define a random baseline, and explain why it is 35% and not 50% for your problem.
2. Get a couple of humans from your client side to try the task manually.
3. Let your model perform the task and show the improvement.

More often than not, humans perform tasks more precisely than models (if in small scale). So, if your model performs better, hopefully, they will see the value your model is adding to their company.